# Scale effect on image inside a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a scale effect on the image inside a flex box. Once the scale effect is applied, the image grows out of the flexbox. I would like the image to scale by staying within the flexbox area. I tried to apply `overflow: hidden` but it did not work. Below is the code snippet:

```css
  

.imageContainer {
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    flex-basis: 32.33333333%;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.imageContainer img {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.thumbnail-container{
webkit-transition: background 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    transition: background 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    &:hover{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="thumbnail-container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Monkey_mustang.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="thumbnail-container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Mustang_mario.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `overflow:hidden` on the thumbnail-container and there is no point animating the background when you are adding the image directly

and also the scale should be applied on the image and not the container

**see solution:**

```css
.imageContainer {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  flex-basis: 32.33333333%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.imageContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

.thumbnail-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-container:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Monkey_mustang.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Mustang_mario.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked and now I understand where I was going wrong! Appreciate your help!

Comment: I actually have one more question on this one: why does the 1st image not cover the whole of flex area like the 2nd image? I know the images are not of equal sizes but a fix for this?

Comment: @Mustang you need to add `width:100%;` to thumbnail container see my update

Comment: I had `width:100%` on the main container, so I assumed that should take care of it. Thank you so much for the solution!